# macOS Monterey Virtualbox VM start error

Tags: windows, macos, virtualbox, virtual-machine, macos-monterey

I have tried setting up a macOS virtual machine for a bit and I have ended up with:

[image: this in the virtual machine screen]

I have followed [this tutorial on YT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YC_PlSk7U8w), and used all the same settings and commands. Is there any way I can fix it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the use of macOS on non-Apple hardware is a legal grey area and as a result "Hackintosh" questions have been deemed [off-topic](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1471/are-hackintosh-questions-allowed).